# Java: parsing ms-word document using POI/HWPF

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, hwpf

I have a ms-word document (MS-Office 2003; non-xml). Within this
document there is a string associated with a bookmark. Furthermore,
the word document contains word-macros. My goal is to read the
document with java, replace the string associated with the bookmark,
and save the document back to word format.

My first approach was using Apache POI HWPF:

```
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("Test.doc"));
doc.write(new FileOutputStream("Test_generated.doc"));
```

The problem with this solution is that the generated file does not
contain the macro anymore (File size of the original document: 32k;
file size of the generated document 19k).

Does anybody now if it's possible to retain all the original info
using POI/HWPF?

Answer (score 2):

never found a solution. The customer had to pay an Aspose-license (expensive) or refrain from using macros.