# Java MS Word libarary

Tags: java, ms-word, hwpf

I've document and I want to change all template parameters like {name}, {address} to my own values. I tried to use POI HWPF Library, but I lost document formatting after saving. Even when I open my MS Word document with POI and save it (*without any changes*) document formatting is lost:) Formatting means centering, font size, etc (there are no any tables or pictures - just 'plain text').

What library I can use for this case? Maybe anyone have expirience with MS Word documents and java.
Requirements: Open Source, Without using any Windows COM components (muliplatform), Not OOXML - Microsoft Word XP 2003.

There are similar question (about truncating document after saving)
[Java: parsing ms-word document using POI/HWPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108886/java-parsing-ms-word-document-using-poi-hwpf)

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell from own experience, but have you tried the [OOo](http://www.openoffice.org/) Java API's? From what I've heard and seen is that they're very good and flexible. And that not only for MS Word documents.

Give it a try.

Comment: it seems to OOo will work fine for my task, because oowriter fine opens and saves target document.